# $L^1$ norm of product of independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to show that $\|XY\|_1 = \|X\|_1\|Y\|_1$ for $X,Y$ independent random variables, where $\|X\|_1 = \int{|X| d\mathbb{P}}$.

I have a feeling that this result is intuitive, but could anyone explain from a measure theoretic perspective why this is true? Thanks

Comment: @tomasz Oh, sorry - I overread this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* means exactly that the joint distribution $P_{X, Y}$ factors as the product measure of $P_X$ and $P_Y$. By the change of variable formula, we have 
$$\int_{\Omega} |XY|\, d P=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |xy|\, P_{X, Y}(dxdy)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|xy|\, P_X(dx)P_Y(dy),$$
and clearly the last integral factors as $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|P_X(dx)\int_{\mathbb{R}}|y|P_Y(dy)$. Applying again the change of variable formula we see that this is exactly $\int_{\Omega}|X|\, dP\int_{\Omega}|Y|\, dP$.

Comment: What is the exact justification for "To say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent means exactly that the joint distribution $P_{X,Y}$ factors as the product measure of $P_X$ and $P_Y$. "

Comment: @1234: That's often given as the definition of "independent random variables". Some authors [and Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables) prefer to say that two random variables are *independent* when their joint cumulative distribution function factors in a product, but it is not hard to show that that condition is equivalent to the factorization of the joint distribution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be proved only using the definition of independence $\mathbb P(AB)=\mathbb P(A)\cdot \mathbb P(B)$ and Lebesgue integral.

We assume that $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative (otherwise we consider their absolute values which still are independent).

Notice that $X$ is the pointwise non-decreasing limit of characteristic functions of measurable sets, and these sets belong to $\sigma(X)$. We do the same for $Y$.

By monotone convergence, it's enough to do it when $X$ and $Y$ are simple and in this case the relationship can be checked easily.